# Prevent Google crawling other folders in /var/www/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, reverse-proxy, google-search-console

We have a website build on Ruby on Rails reverse proxied with Apache. So the root folder for the website would be /var/www/html/digiryte and the folder structure is similar to this

```
/var/www/html/
    rails_website/
    folder1/
    folder2/
    index.html
```

The trouble is google's webmaster console is showing crawl errors with the url like

```
/html/rails_website/public/assets/...
```

How is this possible? 
How can I stop google from indexing those folders?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a robot.txt to Disallow the folder you don't wont to be indexed

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /rails_website/
```

Comment: I want urls in the rails_website to be index but not others folders. I am blank about how google is accessing those folders.

Comment: i think the best way is to make a sitemap.xml for the url you want to indexed and block that folder with robot.txt